# Cómo optimizar el código de mi juego de ahorcado en PHP

Tags: php, html

Cuando escribes una letra y le das a enviar revela la letra, pero cuando vuelves a meter otra letra se reinicia la página y desaparece la letra anteriormente ingresada por el jugador

```
    <?php
$palabra="caballo";
$fin=false;
$paldescubrir="*******";

//-----------------------------------------
function comprobarletra($letra){
    global $palabra;    
    global $paldescubrir;
    global $fallos;
    global $fin;

    if ((strpos ($palabra,$letra)) or ($palabra[0])==$letra){
while((strpos ($palabra,$letra)) or ($palabra[0])==$letra){
    $pos=strpos($palabra,$letra);
    $palabra[$pos]="*";
    $paldescubrir[$pos]=$letra;



}
}

}

//-----------------------------------------
function pintarasteriscos(){
    global $paldescubrir;
    echo $paldescubrir;


}

//-----------------------------------------

function formulario(){
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="trabajo.php" method="post">
INTRODUCE LETRA:
<input type="text" name="letra">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
';
comprobarletra($_POST["letra"]);
pintarasteriscos();
}
//-----------------------------------------

formulario();

?>
```

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte es necesario que coloques el código que hace el archivo trabajo.php que es al que haces submit mediante el POST. **EDIT**: ¿Puede que hayas usado trabajo.php como nombre del archivo?

Comment: Si exacto, el archivo se llama trabajo.php

Answer (score 3):

La solución a tu problema sería **almacenar** la cadena con los carácteres que envias y coinciden con la palabra (en este caso **caballo**).

El problema que tiene tu código, es que al ejecutar un 
**submit** por **POST** ninguna de las variables que defines como global se mantienen, es decir, cada vez que es ejecutado el PHP no se conoce si antes se ha presentado una coincidencia con la palabra.

Un método que puedes utilizar para almacenar la cadena con la coincidencia es usar **variables de sesión ($_SESSION)**.

Adjunto el código (funcionando) implementando las variables de sesión:

```
<?php
// Sentencia que declara que se utilizarán Variables de Sesión
session_start();

$palabra="caballo";
$fin=false;
$paldescubrir="*******";

// Código que se realiza si se presionó el botón con nombre Enviar
if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) { 
    // Definimos la variable de sesión palabradescubierta con el valor del input con nombre Descubriendo
    $_SESSION['palabradescubierta'] = $_POST['Descubriendo'];
    } 

// Si la variable de sesión palabradescubierta tiene un valor, entonces se le asigna a la variable global paldescubrir
if (isset($_SESSION["palabradescubierta"])) {
    $paldescubrir=$_SESSION["palabradescubierta"];
    }

// Código que se realiza si se presionó el botón Reiniciar
if (isset($_POST['Reiniciar'])) { 
    session_destroy();
    $paldescubrir="*******";
    // Destruimos las variables de sesión, es decir, borramos lo que se ha descubierto.
    } 



//-----------------------------------------
function comprobarletra($letra){
    global $palabra;    
    global $paldescubrir;
    global $fallos;
    global $fin;

    if ((strpos ($palabra,$letra)) or ($palabra[0])==$letra){
        while((strpos ($palabra,$letra)) or ($palabra[0])==$letra){
            $pos=strpos($palabra,$letra);
            $palabra[$pos]="*";
            $paldescubrir[$pos]=$letra;
            }
            }
            }

//-----------------------------------------

function formulario(){
comprobarletra($_POST["letra"]);
 global $paldescubrir;

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="trabajo.php" method="post">
INTRODUCE LETRA:
<input type="text" name="letra">
<input type="submit" name="Enviar"><input type="submit" name="Reiniciar" value="Reiniciar"> <br />
<input type="text" name ="Descubriendo" value="' . $paldescubrir . '" readonly>
</form></body></html>';
}
//-----------------------------------------

formulario();

?>
```